# How to do a DC sweep on an oscilloscope?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, pspice, orcad

I created the circuit for a project of mine on Orcad Capture (Pspice). I ran a DC sweep on it and got the desired output. Now I have built the identical circuit on a breadboard but I am not getting the same output on the oscilloscope that I am on the DC sweep graph on my simulation. Is there a certain way to do a DC sweep on an oscilloscope?

Here is my circuit:
[image]

Here is my DC sweep graphical output:

[image]

Comment: Here is my circuit:

Comment: Sweep variable in the settings is V36

Answer (score 2):

Not without other equipment - modern scopes generally do not have an X output.

You will need a function generator that can output a triangle or sawtooth waveform.  Feed the sawtooth signal into the circuit under test and the output into the Y input scope.

If the scope can do an X-Y display then feed the signal from the function generator into the X input.  The scope will then display the DC sweep of the circuit.

If the scope does not support X-Y display you can simulate it by triggering the timebase with the start of the sawtooth from the the function generator and adjust the timebase to display a single cycle.

The frequency of the function generator may require some experiment - from many seconds to tens of cycles per second.  A lot may depend upon the value of any decoupling present in the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

DC sweep is just measuring a bunch of points automatically.  You can put a pot between +/- 12V sources.  Connect the wiper to the amplifier input. Keep in mind the change in source resistance when you do this.  Also you probably want to put resistors off each end of the pot so the range of the pot is +/- 0.1V.  Now just set the input in 10mV increments and get the output at the same setting.  You can then graph this with Excel or pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional scopes have an X axis output. It's a sawtooth waveform, on a BNC socket on the rear of the scope. Voltage will be something like 0 to 5V (defined in the scope's handbook), period will be whatever the timebase is set to.

So, in this example, 0V would refer to the left hand side of the screen, 5V to the right.

Buffer this waveform, amplify, attenuate or scale it as necessary, and apply it as input to the circuit under test.

My Hameg HM-605 (60MHz) has this facility, my newer Tektronix 2465 doesn't. With the latter, I would turn to Kevin White's solution.